# React: changing state onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change a background image state when hovering an element (icon) but I'm always getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "icon" of undefined", which is strange, since the icon is working fine until I hover it.

Glad if anyone could help.

States:

```
this.state = {
      images: {
        header: "path to img",
        icon: "path to icon"
      }
}
```

The method:

```
 handleMouseOver = () => {
    this.setState({
      images: {
        header: "new img"
      }
    });
  };
```

Header component receiving the image:

```
<Header bgImg={this.state.images.header} />
```

Hovered element:

```
<div>
   <img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} src={this.state.images.icon} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue come from your `onMouseOver` function, which set a new value for state but remove icon from the images object. You need to run the following:

```
 handleMouseOver = () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      return {
         images: {
           header: "new img",
           icon: state.images.icon
         }
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: You should use prevState in scenarios like this: `this.setState((prevState) => {...`, `prevState.images.icon`

Comment: Thanks James, totally right , answer has been updated.

Comment: Not like this :) You should use `state` or `prevState` (whatever you call it) in the `setState` function as a callback.

Comment: Ok, but what if there are more than `icon` and `header` properties in the `images` state? :)

Comment: Also, one more thing. You should return your object in your `setState` callback in parens. `()` If you don't do this the arrow function will see it as a body block.

Comment: Using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as descibed by devserkan is a better solution as it perform a shallow merge of images, but I prefered to show it this was to keep the synthax more accessible and not being too broad.

Comment: But this may leads to bugs :) What if OP decides to add a new property to their state? Always use the proper syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you are setting your `images` you are losing `icon` state. Try like this:

```
handleMouseOver = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    images: {
      ...prevState.images,
      header: "new img"
    }
  }));
};
```

You are using the old `images` by spreading it and then update the necessary property. Why we use `setState` callback and `prevState`? Because when we are setting our new state we are depending on our old state.